# Website width on iphone

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have problem with website width on iphone. I've added meta tag:

to header, but still my website ignores scaling on iphone.

You find my website at http://dev.mooaed.com/

Thank you!

Comment: did you notice that you have two `viewport` meta tags? and the second one has an extra comma at the end?

Comment: You have a lot of **[Markup Validation Errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mooaed.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)**

Comment: Beyond your viewport issues others have pointed out, your site works just fine on mine despite a minimum width that is too large to support the smaller screen of an iphone 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace both your viewport meta tags with this. I think the syntax is incorrect.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1" />
```

Comment: Seems right to me.  You might also include Brewal's link from above about the his markup errors.

Comment: Still no help, it doesn't fit to window even after chaning your tag given. I was trying to render iphone/android on chrome, but on browser everything seems to be okay. When I go to real device website still dont want to fit to window.